# Best way to write JUnit tests for SOAP service

Tags: unit-testing, testing, soap

What are the best Junit tests for soap services.

Would connecting to the web service fall under a unit test or an integration test?

I need to pick useful unit tests and was looking for ideas on tests that would be automatable and repeatable.

Thanks.

Comment: Better late than never - https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unit tests, you should test an isolated behavior of a single class, and therefore use mocks/stubs/test doubles as much as possible. If you do not mock, then you are not testing an isolated part of your code. Hence isolating the error becomes more difficult and the test might also not be repeatable (e.g. strange network behavior might occur unrepeatably).

You should also try to automate your integration tests, where you replace your mocked objects with the real implementations.

[At this infoq site](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/05/WSMock) you can find a short introduction about mocking web services, and several links to tutorials/tools/whitepapers.